# How to set JPA attribute with AccessLevel.NONE for unit test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, lombok

This is `User` entity class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

And this is `UserServiceTest` class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { UserService.class })
public class UserServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetName() {
        int id = 2;
        User mockUser = new User();
        mockUser.setId(id)          // Error Here
        mockUser.setName("John");
        Optional<User> mockUserOptional = Optional.of(mockUser);
        Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(id)).thenReturn(mockUserOptional);
        ...
    } 
}
```

I want to set the id of `mockUser` but cannot access it. Is there a solution to set the field that has `AccessLevel.NONE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is, but it involves reflection. As noted, `@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)` means there is no setter, and `id` is `private`, so there is no ‘legal’ way to write to it.

There is a plain Java way, but since you are already using Spring, I recommend `ReflectionTestUtils`, to be used like that:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(user, "id", 42);
```

PS 1: You really should not use `int` as the type for `id`, but `Integer` instead. Otherwise, there is no way to distinguish between a fresh entity and an entity with an `id` of zero.
PS 2: Your `mockUser` is not a mock.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set that field in an unitary way from the client side, why do you use : `AccessLevel.NONE` ? 
It is contradictory since it means : [don't generate anything](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/AccessLevel.html#NONE) :

> `public static final AccessLevel NONE`
>
> Represents not generating anything or the complete lack of a method.

About :

> I want to set the id of mockUser but it can't access. Is there a
>   solution to set the field with AccessLevel.NONE ?

Write a setter for or remove this annotation.
And for the sake of your application, don't use reflection for such a thing.

Comment: You probably want to change it to `@Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)` instead. That makes it available for code inside the same package, including your unit tests.

Comment: There’s no need to do that, and I wouldn’t recommend it for JPA generated IDs.

Comment: @Roel Spilker The entity is not necessarily in the package of the class that uses that (`UserService`).

Comment: @Michael Piefel A code has to be naturally testable and reflection is error prone : we want to use that for fair reasons.

Comment: Code that can change the id that JPA assigned to the entity is error-prone, too. Choose your poison.

Comment: @Michael Piefel  Code that can change the id is error prone, sure. But unit tests have also this goal : ensuring that a misuse doesn't exist and tests with a minimal level of quality will do that.